# Query SQL condição se

Tags: sql, query

Estou com um problema em fazer uma query onde tenho 3 campos e basta um deles estar preenchido que já não mostra esse resultado.

Alguem me consegue ajudar a fazer isso?

```
select * from tabelas where campo1 and campo2 and campo3
```

Comment: E o php? poderia colocar a cosulta verdadeira.

Comment: Na parte `where campo1 and campo2 and campo3` você tem que colocar alguma comparação, por exemplo, `campo1 == 10`, se na verdade você só queria selecionar esses campos, então eles entram no `select` e não no `where`. Por exemplo, `select campo1, campo2, campo3 from tabelas`.

Comment: Você quer dizer "basta um deles NÃO estar preenchido" né? Faltou dizer qual é o resultado que você quer.

Comment: Como o carlos disse, provavelmente você está confundindo os campos... tente desta maneira:
`select campo1, campo2, campo3 from tabelas`

Answer (score 3):

Se tu quer que todos sejam mostrados a menos que uma esteja preenchida faça isso:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabelas
WHERE campo1 IS NULL
  AND campo2 IS NULL
  AND campo3 IS NULL
```

Se tu quer aonde todos estão preenchidos use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabelas
WHERE campo1 IS NOT NULL
  AND campo2 IS NOT NULL
  AND campo3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `COALESCE` para identificar se todos os campos estão nulos (combinado com `is null`), ou se algum deles está preenchido (`is not null`):

```
select * from tabelas where coalesce(campo1, campo2, campo3) is null;

select * from tabelas where coalesce(campo1, campo2, campo3) is not null;
```

[Exemplo no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1011c/2)

Comment: Há algum ganho de performance, comparando à resposta do Andrey?

Comment: Não encontrei nada a respeito, mas isso depende da implementação do `COALESCE` no banco de dados utilizado. Em SQL Server, por exemplo, o `COALESCE` é convertido em `case when` internamente, portanto pode haver ganho dependendo do modelo de dados. Por exemplo, se o `campo1` tiver um índice e os demais campos não, nos casos em que `campo1` estiver preenchido o engine do SQL Server nem precisaria verificar os outros campos, já que o `case` seria interrompido no primeiro campo.